# I am having trouble with this runtime exception message I keep getting regarding ShareActionProvider in android

Tags: java, android, exception, classcastexception, shareactionprovider

Here is the runtime exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider cannot be cast to android.view.View

I have tried many different ways of doing this but I know it has to do with the ShareActionProvider I can add links to sites where there are several ways of doing this but it is not working here is the entire code

And by "this" I mean instantiating the ShareActionProvider

Please to not set this as duplicate it is not I have looked on SO and none of them have helped ... Sod to say

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    MenuInflater inflator = getMenuInflater();
    inflator.inflate(R.menu.sidebar_menu, menu);
    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Themes");
    subMenu.add(0 , blue , 0 , "Blue");
    subMenu.add(0, pink , 1, "Pink");
    items = subMenu.getItem().getItemId();

    // tool bar menu
    MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.searchable);
    mi.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mi);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    sap = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menu.findItem(R.id.share));
    Intent intentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intentShare.setType("text/plain");
    intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT ,"Subject here");
    intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , "Here is the share content body");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShare,"Share via"));
    sap.setShareIntent(intentShare);
MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener el = new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener(){
        @Override
   public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        // Do something when action item collapses
        return true; // Return true to collapse action view
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
    // Do something when expanded
    return true; // Return true to expand action view
    }};
   MenuItem actionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchable);

   // Assign the listener to that action item
   MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(actionMenuItem,el);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Can anyone help please ! I think I have been clear enough with this issue I am having if needed I can post up the menu.XML file along with appmanifest.XML along with the other XML files which I see no reason to put up ... Thank you

Here is the menu.xml as requested

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/searchable"
    android:title="@string/tbmenuitem_search"
    myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" 
/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/sharetitle"
    myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/playlist"
    android:title="Play lists"
/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/muteoption"
    android:title="Mute"
/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/unmuteoption"
    android:title="UnMute"
/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/sharewidget"
    android:title="Share"
/>
```

[Edited] my XML file actionViewClass should have been actionViewProvider hence the run time error .

Comment: What is "sap" declared as?

Comment: private ShareActionProvider sap; trust me it is

Comment: I have read this over and over I do not know what I am doing wrong sir please help !

Comment: post your menu xml

Comment: Okay I already posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ShareActionProvider from support v7 library doesn´t work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873875/shareactionprovider-from-support-v7-library-doesn%c2%b4t-work)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873875/shareactionprovider-from-support-v7-library-doesn%C2%B4t-work that seems to be your problem

Comment: Okay I read it over and over but still don't understand what to do please help ! @Scrotos

Comment: Post your full activity code please. You sure your class is correct?

Comment: My manifest.xml does have a parent and child

Comment: Okay I will do that as we speak thank you so much

Comment: I am having trouble formatting the code I'm on a phone I can't indent just please take my word for it everything is correct . what can it possibly be ?

Comment: How can I indent all code there is about 400 lines of code . is their a way to do that on a android phone without having to indent each line ? That would be useful in the future @Scrotos

Comment: My class extends AppCompatActivity yes it is correct can anyone help please